# Can the boundary of any closed curve be represented as a series of circles of the same diameter (or any other geometrical shape)

Tags: geometry, curves

The boundary of a simple closed curve has each point on it, touching two adjacent points one on each side. Can the entire boundary be represented as a series of circles of the same diameter "d" where each circle is touching the adjacent circle at exactly one point only without overlap in areas between the two circles.

This will allow us to approximate the simple closed curve with a polygon where each side of the polygon is represented by a line joining the centers of adjacent circles and at a distance equal to the diameter "d" of the circle.

Such approximation would imply that a inscribed square exists on the polygon (Toeplitz conjecture special cases) and therefore an "almost square" whose vertices are within the error range of the diameter of the circle must exist. Shrinking the size of the circles used will reduce the error of the "almost squares" to smaller and smaller values.
[image]

Comment: First, a point on a simple closed curve does not have "two adjacent points one on each side"; lines don't even work that way (real numbers don't have successors). Second, I think any closed curve with a corner (such as a triangle) shows that the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I did not the two points touching the middle point to be diametrically opposite but just two points touch a point in between at varied positions from one part of curve to another. Please find an image I added.

Comment: What's written in the OP is partly wrong, partly meaningless, partly a wishful thinking.

Comment: Thank you Moishe. I assume giving a point a dimension is the main flaw and I am only approximating the curve with a series of line segments?

Comment: Thanks again Greg, right triangle with sides of length 1, 1, (2^1/2), cannot be fitted with integral number of circles for any diameter.

Comment: You should define precisely what you mean by "represented", in the title sentence ("Can the boundary of any closed curve be represented as a series of circles of the same diameter (or any other geometrical shape)"). Is it that the contact points between two adjacent circles are on the curve? Is it that the circle centers are on the curve? Or any other definition?

Comment: Thanks Jean-Armand, my initial thought was to think of the centers to represent the points on the curve.

Comment: If instead of zooming into dimensional points on the boundary of a curve and imagine them as circles, I wonder if one can imagine two simple closed curves of the same exact shape but of slightly different sizes and imagine drawing a polygon in the thin area bounded between the two curves to approximate both the curves. Then an inscribed square must exist for this polygon. And as the bounded area reduces in size, the inscribed square on polygon will be "almost inscribed square for the curve" and possibly allowing us to prove an inscribed square for the curve itself within an error range? Thanks

Comment: sidenote: if you are thinking about the inscribed square problem, you should perhaps look at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/11/22/an-integration-approach-to-the-toeplitz-square-peg-problem/. Even the "smoothest type of curve that was not already covered by previous results" case remains difficult; Tao simplifies and reduces the problem further to a combinatorial question that I think is still open.

Comment: Thanks DR. The proof seems a bit intimidating but will try.